# How do I determine if I need to dispatch to UI thread in WinRT/Metro?

Tags: .net, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

In .NET you have `System.Threading.Thread.IsBackground`.

Is there some equivalent of this in WinRT/Metro?

I have a method which changed UI properties, and I want to determine whether or not I need to dispatch the execution to the UI thread runtime.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, if you use **[MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)** in your app, you can use **CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(Action action)** method of **GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading.DispatcherHelper** class which handles this situation automatically.

```
GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading.DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
{
    Gui.Property = SomeNewValue;
});
```

**Edit:**

The following code is based on **DispatcherHelper** class of **MVVM Light Toolkit** - **[link](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4be0aa663f97#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29/Threading/DispatcherHelper.cs)**

But if you don't want to use MVVM Light (*which is pretty cool thing by the way*), you can try something like this (sorry, can't check if this works, don't have Windows 8):

```
var dispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

if (dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
    UIUpdateMethod();
else dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => UIUpdateMethod(););
```

It would be nicer to put this logic in separate class like this:

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace MyProject.Threading
{
    public static class DispatcherHelper
    {
        public static CoreDispatcher UIDispatcher { get; private set; }

        public static void CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(Action action)
        {
            if (UIDispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
                action();
            else UIDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                       () => action());
        }

        static DispatcherHelper()
        {
            if (UIDispatcher != null)
                return;
            else UIDispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
DispatherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => UIUpdateMethod());
```

Comment: I guess this works, but it would be nice if anyone knew of a solution not requiring a third party library.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess the Window.Current.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess bool is the key.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the main ui thread through CoreApplication.Window, e.g.

```
 if (CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
            {
                DoStuff();
            }
            else
            {
                await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    DoStuff();
                });
            }
```